# Generating user id in SQL by concatenating

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a script that generates automatically by concatenating the first letter of the first_name and the first seven characters of the last_name. Therefore, the generated userid must be in lowercase. Hence the script should not prompt for the userid.

I must use it for insertions. There it is but I don't know how to make it work.

```
    INSERT INTO my_employee 
   (
    id,
    last_name,
    first_name,
    userid,
    salary
   )
    VALUES (&id,
            &last_name,
            &first_name,
            LOWER(SUBSTR(first_name,1,1) || SUBSTR(last_name,1,7)),
            &salary);
```

Well thanks to Shantanu's ideea i have found the solution, not the brightest in the world but it does the job :D :

```
INSERT INTO my_employee 
     VALUES ( &id,
             '&last_name',
             '&first_name',
              NULL,
              &salary); 
UPDATE my_employee
SET    userid = LOWER(SUBSTR(last_name,1,1) || SUBSTR(first_name,1,7))
WHERE  userid IS NULL;
```

Comment: Other than not having lower() on the first 7 characters of the last name, what's the problem with the posted code?  Oh I see, you have to use variables inside those functions, the fields don't exist yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

easiest way will be to insert values for id, last_name, first_name, salary from the prompt

and then use update to put userid with your logic: LOWER(SUBSTR(first_name,1,1)|| SUBSTR(last_name,1,7))

Comment: Why to make it so complex? The `insert` could be done at one go. Why do you want to do it in two steps?

Comment: that's because per udarH3: the "user" should not enter twice the last_name and first_name in the end. That was the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to have the `PROMPT` in the `SUBSTR` too.

For example,

```
SQL> SELECT substr('&ename', 1, 1) || substr('&ename', 1, 7) FROM dual
  2  /
Enter value for ename: abcdefgh
Enter value for ename: abcdefgh
old   1: SELECT substr('&ename', 1, 1) || substr('&ename', 1, 7) FROM dual
new   1: SELECT substr('abcdefgh', 1, 1) || substr('abcdefgh', 1, 7) FROM dual

SUBSTR('
--------
aabcdefg

SQL>
```

Modify your query to,

```
INSERT INTO my_employee 
   (
    id,
    last_name,
    first_name,
    userid,
    salary
   )
    VALUES (&id,
            &last_name,
            &first_name,
            LOWER(SUBSTR(&first_name,1,1) || SUBSTR(&last_name,1,7)),
            &salary);
```

Comment: Forgot to say that i used the ampersand(PROMPT) in the SUBSTR too and still doesn't work, i've tested the functions with dummy table too etc. But still i didn't managed to make it work. When using prompt in substr i recive "column not allowed in here". Anyway why should the "user" enter twice the last_name and first_name in the end? :)

Comment: Something doesn't work is not a standard Oracle error. Can you please elaborate and show your session, what you actually tried?

Comment: like i said, i tried different types of coding, including your example before i saw it and it doesn't work, i get the error ORA-00984: column not allowed here, but with the one above wich is in my question area it does the job. Now regarding your question, i don't understand what are you asking me to do.